# Android - Capture and convert objects from Pictures to Canvas

Tags: android, image

When taking a picture of an object (for example, a Window). Is it possible to capture the outline of a window and display the contents on the canvas.

For example,

[image: Window]

and convert this picture of the window and displays it on the Android display

[image]

Any help or pointers to tutorials would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Hi, what you describe here can either be a very difficult image processing task or it can be as simple as applying something like the [Sobel_Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an edge detection algorithm is what you want. As Renard said, this can be simple providing your input is simple like the window. Complex imagery is much harder to find edges on.
You might cruise through the [Open Computer Vision library](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) (OpenCV)  to see if there's something there you can use algorithmically